# How coordinate lines transform under $e^z=\frac{a-w}{a+w}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked this question as part of a homework assignment. I'm assuming $w$ is my transformation function such that $w=f(z)$ and that the coordinate lines in question are the cartesian coordinate lines.

What I've tried is to solve for $w$ 
$$w=\frac{a(1-e^z)}{1+e^z}$$

And consider the case $x=constant$ and $y=constant$ and see if I can see anything. This has proven to be extremely tedious and hardly illuminating if at all.

I was hoping someone could give me any hint. By the way, these transformations are in the context of complex variables and from a course on mathematical physics, in case you needed to know.

Comment: I've done a matlab simulation and it seems they map into circles and rays, but I don't see why.. Any ideas?

Comment: With this I mean: Without having to afterwards prove that e.g. the modulus is always a constant therefore it maps into a circle, etc , which would be impossible for me to see at a glance.